# Loading next scene when counter is down to 0

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to let my Unity project load next scene when the counter I have is down to 0. However I am unable to do that for some reason. The way I am trying to do it by :

```
    int i = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;

    void Update () {
     if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Birds") == null)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(i + 1);
        }
    }
```

In the editor I have created a folder where I have made 3 scenes. Have called them Level 1, Level 2 etc.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have 3 scenes

Comment: What index does your active scene have, in the build window?

Comment: I haven't build it yet, I am testing it on the editor. Shouldn't it work on it?

Comment: You need to actually add the scenes to the build order to access them from the scene manager. Then, you go by their indexes. So assuming you added them in order, level one would be 0, level two would be 1 and so on.

Comment: You don't need to build the game, the levels just need to be added from the build window.

Comment: Have done that, but I still have the same problem :(

Comment: Can you describe the symptoms of the problem in more detail? Are you getting an error message? Is the wrong scene being loaded? Have you confirmed whether your birds == null check is ever triggering? Are you using multi-scene editing at all? Without this info, it can be tricky to narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 1):

You can see here in the build settings that there are numbers next to each scene you have. After you have dragged your scenes into the build settings here you will be able to specify which scene to load by using that number next to the scene. Using `SceneManager.LoadScene(i + 1);` will work if the next scene in line in the build settings is the scene you are wanting to move from your current scene. [image]

So for example, say I am in the title scene and I have a button that is used to move on to the game scene. When that button is pressed I would use `SceneManager.LoadScene(i + 1);` to move to the game scene since it is the next in line in build settings.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop the scene from assets into the hierarchy bar, then unload the scene to proceed in editor.

[image]

Now, when you're in the first scene (AR2) and you call the next scene (AR1) then you'll get that scene. Don't forget that you need to keep these scenes alive if you want to go back and forth between them as the editor will unload scenes if they call another scene load.